# How to highlight a button in html page when i click on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, php

I have four buttons on the page, when I click on one of them i want it to be highlighted.

The buttons are used to pass data to a controller. 
They are like this:

```
<button name="region" id="region" type="button"  onclick="window.location='/project/Viewdata/index/region/1'" class="current">ALL</button>
<button name="region" id="region2" type="button"  onclick="window.location='/project/Viewdata/index/region/2'" class="current">1st</button>
```

Comment: You can't have two elements with the same id!

Comment: buttons have redirect code. wouldn't they redirect after click?

Comment: yes that is a problem i am facing, because of redirect option its loading the basic settings

Comment: is there any reason not to use normal links?

Comment: and i changed the id's :)

Comment: actually i am sending data to a controller on the same page... and displaying data with the help of grid, so i am not able to use ajax to send data, so i m sending it via url...

Comment: again..why not use a normal link with `hover` css? and ajax would be possible, too if you would use an javascript based grid or return the whole grid on ajax call..

Comment: how can i return the whole grid on ajax call?? can you please suggest the code

Answer (score 4):

check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3bMVP/20/)

basically, you bind a highligt effect to the button with jQuery, when clicking it like this

```
$('button').click(function() {
    $(this).effect( "highlight", {color: 'red'}, 3000 );
});
```

NOTE: As said in the comments, you should never have 2 elements with the same id on one page. If you want to use the same descriptor, use `class` instead of `id`

Comment: tried the same previously... but it didn't work... and i ve changed the id's but still no result...