# CSS Button Highlight post click

Tags: css, button, focus, highlight

I have three buttons in my view. I want the button to be highlighted not only during a click but post a click (unless another click is made). I know how to highlight the button on click but I want the highlight to last until a new click is made. Is there any way to do it??

Comment: Are you looking for a script solution or a pure css solution?

Comment: anything will do..preferably CSS

Comment: It can't be done with pure CSS. You'll need JavaScript. Post a jsfiddle and I'm sure someone can help you add the script to your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to highlight a button in html page when i click on it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17747112/how-to-highlight-a-button-in-html-page-when-i-click-on-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a fiddle that should do it in pure CSS. You will not be able to use actual buttons. But you can style the label as I have to look like buttons.

**NOTE:** This will not work properly in older browsers such as IE8

http://jsfiddle.net/ghvst26b/

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" checked id="Button1" value="1"/>
<label class="Button" for="Button1">Button 1</label>
<input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" id="Button2" value="2"/>
<label class="Button" for="Button2">Button 2</label>
<input type="radio" name="Button" class="ButtonState" id="Button3" value="3"/>
<label class="Button" for="Button3">Button 3</label>
```

**CSS**

```
.ButtonState{display:none}
.Button{padding:3px; margin:4px; background:#CCC; border:1px solid #333; cursor:pointer;}
.ButtonState:checked + .Button{background:#fff;}
```

Comment: Otherwise as @GarySpectrum  mentioned you would have to use Javascript to add and remove classes for the active button.

Answer (score 3):

**Jquery version**

HTML

```
<button onclick=Highlight(this)/>
```

JQuery

```
function Highlight(button) {
   $(".Highlight").removeClass("Highlight");
   $(button).addClass("Highlight");
}
```