# Keep an element highlighted when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Following is my code-

```js
$("li span").click(function() {
   $("li span").each(function() {
          $(this).css("background-color", "transparent");
   });
  $(this).css("background-color", "#ff3300");
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: green;
}
span {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-menu-inner scroll-pane">
  <ul class="left-menu-list left-menu-list-root list-unstyled">
      <li class="left-menu-list-active">
          <div class="left-menu-link">
          <a href="dashboard">
            <i class="left-menu-link-icon icmn-home2"><!-- --></i>
            <span class="menu-top-hidden">Dashboard</span>
          </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also, I tried another code as follows-

```
<script>
// Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
var header = document.getElementById("myDIV");
var btns = header.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
 btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
   var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
   current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
   this.className += " active";
 });
}
</script>
```

But both of the codes are only highlighting the label on mouseover but not keeping highlighted on onclick.

Comment: this is already highlighted just replace  href with   <a href="javascript:void(0)">

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Button Highlight post click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311659/css-button-highlight-post-click)

Comment: Thank you for your solutions, I tried them but still it is not working for me. Is there any other solution, please?

Comment: can you please elaborate more on "still not working"? What is happening? Because this code is working, it highligth with red background then it redirect to another page. Also, it didn't highlight in mouseover as you said.

Comment: Since you didn't put event.preventDefault() the page will reload when clicking a button, probably removing the "active" class again for all buttons because the browser does not keep state like that

Comment: @CalvinNunes I am using anchor tag. With this code, when I clicked on link anchor tag color is changed but it is like color is getting flash it is not keeping the anchor activated

Comment: It happens because the page reloads or redirect to another one, exactly because it is an anchor tag... or you set an event/listener with `event.preventDefault()` or you set an `href` that didn't reload or redirect, such as `href="#"`.

Answer (score 0):

Above your using 'a' tag so if we click 'a' tag as we know it will jump to mentioned url in 'href', but it can be done by changing url to '#' as i tried in below example , You can also done by replacing 'a' tag to any other tags like 'p'

```
`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-menu-inner scroll-pane">
  <ul class="left-menu-list left-menu-list-root list-unstyled">
      <li class="left-menu-list-active">
          <div class="left-menu-link">
          <a href="#">
            <i class="left-menu-link-icon icmn-home2"><!-- --></i>
            <span class="menu-top-hidden">Dashboard</span>
          </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>`
```

[Click here for Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/985258/)